# Text Color Transition Effect from Bottom to Top

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

How can i let the text color changing from black to red with a css transition effect (e.g. ease-out) from bottom to top for a specific height in percent?

I got a value - let's say 50%. So now i want to change the text color of my example text: example from black to red with a css transition effect. But the transition effect should start at the bottom and then go ahead to top (and not from left to right as many examples demonstrate it). In the end the text "example" should be half colored with black - from bottom to the middle of the test (50%) and half colored with red - from the middle of the text to top (100%).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey @Opa114 please take a look at my codepen to understand how I achieved this effect https://codepen.io/akinhwan/pen/JvmJpO

```
a {
  font: 300 42px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  margin-left: 80px;
  color: $main-color;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    0deg,
    $secondary-color,
    $secondary-color 50%,
    $main-color 50%);
    background-size: 100% 200%;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
}

a:hover {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.000, 0.230, 1);
  background-position: 100% 100%;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient
background-size and background-position are important here to control the effect

Comment: yeah the hint with background-position did it. So in my case i have set the second percentage parameter to for e.g. 50% then only the half of the text will be colored in the secondary color - right?

Answer (score 3):

There are many methods to make the effect, I recommend for a smoother transition, create in the background a gradient with the colors you want to use and move the background to a position where only the colors you want are visible.

```css
h1{
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  color: transparent;
  background-position-y: -0%;
  background-image: linear-gradient( black, red, white, green );
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  transition: background 1400ms ease;
  background-size: auto 400%;
}
h1.deg1{
  background-position-y: -100%;
}
h1.deg2{
  background-position-y: -200%;
}
h1.deg3{
  background-position-y: -300%;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="prueba"> Hola Mundo</h1>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('prueba').className='deg1'"> Cambiar 1 </button> 
<button onclick="document.getElementById('prueba').className='deg2'"> Cambiar 2 </button> 
<button onclick="document.getElementById('prueba').className='deg3'"> Cambiar 2 </button>
```

Comment: yeah another nice solution i think. i will take a look on it.